# GridSearchCV no reporting on high verbosity

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Okay, I'm just going to say starting out that I'm entirely new to SciKit-Learn and data science. But here is the issue and my current research on the problem. Code at the bottom.

### Summary

I'm trying to do type recognition (like digits, for example) with a BernoulliRBM and I'm trying to find the correct parameters with GridSearchCV. However I don't see anything going on. With a lot of examples using verbosity settings I see output and progress, but with mine it just says,

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 15 candidates, totalling 45 fits
```

Then it sits there and does nothing....forever (or 8 hours, the longest I've waited with high verbosity settings).

I have a pretty large data set (1000 2D arrays each of size 428 by 428), so this might be the problem but I've also set the verbosity to 10 so I feel like I should be seeing some kind of output or progress. Also, in terms of my "target", it is just either a 0 or a 1, either it is the object I'm looking for (1), or it isn't (0).

### Previous Research

- I looked into sklearn.preprocessing to see if that was necessary, it doesn't seem to be the issue (but again, I'm entirely new to this).
- I increased verbosity
- I switched from using a 3D list of data to using a list of scipy csr matrices.
- I waited 8 hours with high verbosity settings, I still don't see anything happening.
- I switched from not using a pipeline, to using a pipeline
- I tampered with various parameters of gridsearchcv and tried creating fake (smaller) data sets to practice on.

  ```
  def network_trainer(self, data, files):
      train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data, files, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

      parameters = {'learning_rate':np.arange(.25, .75, .1), 'n_iter':[5, 10, 20]}
      model = BernoulliRBM(random_state=0, verbose=True)
      model.cv = 2
      model.n_components = 2

      logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
      pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('model', model), ('clf', logistic)])

      gscv = grid_search.GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)
      gscv.fit(train_x, train_y)
      print gscv.best_params_
  ```

I'd really appreciate a nudge in the right direction here. Thanks for considering my issue.

Comment: Can you try it with `n_jobs=1`? In my experience, verbose output seems to work not so well with multiprocessing (though I usually run it from IPython notebooks, which might be the origin of the problem in my case).

Comment: @Barmaley.exe Thank you! It still isn't working but at least I have error messages to go with now. I just hate not having errors to work with. I'll update on here when I get it figured out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, so just to summarize everything I've figured out about it over the past few days.

- On Windows 8.1 don't set n_jobs to anything other than 1 if you still want it to be verbose.
- In my case, even though I only have n_jobs = 1, all of my processor cores were still involved in the calculations, so either this is a bug or should be better documented.
- I made the horrible mistake of using a list of csr matrices, so basically, read the documentation and then read it again before you ask questions.

Again I'd like to thank @Barmaley.exe for the initial tip.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue almost 6 years later and setting n_jobs = 1 actually made verbose work. Despite the fact that there is no printing of the process, does it means that with n_jobs = -1 (or any other value than 1 or None) it doesn't make any calculation?

Comment: @Isaac GS Since then, could you find another solution to run both n_jobs=-1 and verbose>=2? You also stated `In my case, even though I only have n_jobs = 1, all of my processor cores were still involved`, does it involve all of them (might be too much for the computer) or only n_jobs-1?

Comment: Note that you can still use multiple jobs by setting n_jobs on your *estimator*. For example: `random_forest_estimator = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=8);
search = GridSearchCV(random_forest_estimator, param_space, n_jobs=1)`

Answer (score 4):

When you run GridSearchCV with `n_jobs` ≠ 1 in a jupyter notebook, the output of the search can be found in the terminal you used to start the jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that GridSearch does not output anything when run with more than 1 thread. 
When all threads are finished it prints out everything.
And multithreading does not work in Windows - use n_jobs > 1 only in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ipython notebook and Python 2.x? If yes then multiprocessing module doesn't work with this combination. You can export (save as) your ipython notebook as a regular .py file and run it with regular python interpreter. Then you can use n_jobs=-1

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that if you don't get any output for some time besides setting `n_jobs = 1` check the verbosity setting of the model you are using. I was using `KerasClassifier` with `verbose=0` and had to set that to `verbose=2` to see the epochs. Pretty obvious when you think about it, nevertheless I spend some time on finding the reason.