# Why verbose=True unable to print messages in jupyter notebook? How to solve it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have installed jupyter notebook in conda environment where I installed tensorflow and keras. After that I unable to display messages by using `verbose=True` . Outside conda environment it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

Comment: I am unable to display the logs of Gridsearchcv using verbose.

Comment: Hi @SubhasisMishra 
Sorry, I was on a stackoverflow hiatus - I was logged in to a different account all this time 

Anyways, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005307/gridsearchcv-no-reporting-on-high-verbosity

It seems to be an issue with multiprocessing